# Convert column values to lower case only if they are string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm having real trouble converting a column into lowercase. It's not as simple as just using:

```
df['my_col'] = df['my_col'].str.lower()
```

because I'm iterating over a lot of dataframes, and some of them (but not all) have both strings and integers in the column of interest. This causes the lower function, if applied like above, to throw an exception:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Rather than forcing the type to be a string, I'd like to assess whether values are strings and then - if they are - convert them to lowercase, and - if they are not strings - leave them as they are. I thought this would work:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.lower() if(isinstance(x, str)) else x)
```

But it doesn't work... probably because I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't see what it is!

My data looks something like this:

```
                          OS    Count
0          Microsoft Windows     3
1                   Mac OS X     4
2                      Linux     234
3    Don't have a preference     0
4  I prefer Windows and Unix     3
5                       Unix     2
6                        VMS     1
7         DOS or ZX Spectrum     2
```

Comment: You could just do `df['my_col'] = df['my_col'].astype(str).str.lower()` to force everything to `str`, is there a reason to have mixed `dtype` as this is non-performant

Comment: Ah... I'm not sure. Will the astype(str) not convert all the integers in the "Count" column into strings when returned? And if so, won't that prevent later arithmetic operations?

I should add that into the original question...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The test in your lambda function isn't quite right, you weren't far from the truth though:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower() if(x.dtype == 'object') else x)
```

With the data frame and output:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'OS': 'Microsoft Windows', 'Count': 3},
        {'OS': 'Mac OS X', 'Count': 4},
        {'OS': 'Linux', 'Count': 234},
        {'OS': 'Dont have a preference', 'Count': 0},
        {'OS': 'I prefer Windows and Unix', 'Count': 3},
        {'OS': 'Unix', 'Count': 2},
        {'OS': 'VMS', 'Count': 1},
        {'OS': 'DOS or ZX Spectrum', 'Count': 2},
    ]
)
>>> df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower() if x.dtype=='object' else x)
>>> print(df)
                          OS  Count
0          microsoft windows      3
1                   mac os x      4
2                      linux    234
3     dont have a preference      0
4  i prefer windows and unix      3
5                       unix      2
6                        vms      1
7         dos or zx spectrum      2
```

Comment: Thanks. The other answer was also good, but this one tested for the object before applying the lowercase, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

What is the type of these columns to begin with? `object`? If so, you should just convert them:

```
df['my_col'] = df.my_col.astype(str).str.lower()
```

MVCE:

```
In [1120]: df
Out[1120]: 
   Col1
0   VIM
1   Foo
2  test
3     1
4     2
5     3
6   4.5
7   OSX

In [1121]: df.astype(str).Col1.str.lower()
Out[1121]: 
0     vim
1     foo
2    test
3       1
4       2
5       3
6     4.5
7     osx
Name: Col1, dtype: object

In [1118]: df.astype(str).Col1.str.lower().dtype
Out[1118]: dtype('O')
```

If you want to do arithmetic on these rows, you probably shouldn't be mixing `str`s and numeric types.

However, if that is indeed your case, you may typecast to numeric using `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')`:

```
In [1123]: pd.to_numeric(df.Col1, errors='coerce')
Out[1123]: 
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    3.0
6    4.5
7    NaN
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```

You can work with the NaNs, but notice the `dtype` now.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that the types shouldn't be mixed. The problem is that this is user-entered data, and it's very difficult to stop people from doing so! Next time, I need better constraints on user input.

Comment: @user4896331 Until then, `pd.to_numeric` is your friend. Take a look at my answer if you didn't see the edit before.

Answer (score 3):

From the above two answers I think doing this is a bit more safer way:

Note the `astype(str)`

```
df_lower=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower() if(x.dtype == 'object') else x)
```

Because if your string column by chance contains only numbers in some rows, not doing `astype(str)` converts them to nan. This might be a bit slower but it wont convert rows with just numbers to nan.

Answer (score 1):

This also works and is very readable:

```
for column in df.select_dtypes("object").columns:
    df[column] = df[column].str.lower()
```

A possible drawback might be the `for` loop over a subset of columns.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do using list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [x.lower() for x in df.columns]
```